Looking for assistance with Node-Red trigger node as a dynamic timer
Killing myself over this one and hoping someone can help.
The issue: In the impending JSON node-red flow I have created an automation for my fireplace.  Everything seems to work correctly with the exception of an auto-off timer I have implemented.  The timer gets a value from 'input_number.auto_off_fireplace_timing' (set by the user).  This number is then sent as msg.auto_off_timing = entity_state.  A function node received this and runs the following JS against it:
const timingMinutes = Number(msg.auto_off_timing);

if (isNaN(timingMinutes) || timingMinutes <= 0) {
    node.error("Invalid timing value", msg);
    return null;
}

const timingMilliseconds = timingMinutes * 60 * 1000;

msg.delay = timingMilliseconds;
delete msg.reset;
return msg;

It then sends this message to the Auto-off Timer Trigger Node, which seems to start (blue circle present) but does not abide by the math outlined.  In fact, I can't get it to continue on from the trigger and given the node type, there is no good way to monitor the current status of its countdown.
At a lost here and hoping someone can help.  here is my JSON (some of the other safety checks, thermostat, auto-off after 2 hours, etc... have been removed to focus on the issue):
[
    {
        "id": "109ae81398e4db33",
        "type": "subflow",
        "name": "Automation Gate (5) (5) (2) (3)",
        "info": "This subflow checks the status of input_boolean.nodered_enable and allows automations to proceed only if it is 'on'.",
        "category": "",
        "in": [
            {
                "x": 60,
                "y": 80,
                "wires": [
                    {
                        "id": "6a0e54df8bebfb35"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "out": [
            {
                "x": 460,
                "y": 80,
                "wires": [
                    {
                        "id": "6a0e54df8bebfb35",
                        "port": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "env": [],
        "color": "#DDAA99",
        "icon": "node-red/switch.svg",
        "status": {
            "x": 460,
            "y": 140,
            "wires": [
                {
                    "id": "6a0e54df8bebfb35",
                    "port": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "6a0e54df8bebfb35",
        "type": "api-current-state",
        "z": "109ae81398e4db33",
        "name": "Check nodered_enable",
        "server": "home_assistant",
        "version": 3,
        "outputs": 2,
        "halt_if": "on",
        "halt_if_type": "str",
        "halt_if_compare": "is",
        "entity_id": "input_boolean.nodered_enable",
        "state_type": "str",
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "nodered_enable",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            }
        ],
        "for": 0,
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "x": 260,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "home_assistant",
        "type": "server",
        "name": "Home Assistant",
        "addon": true
    },
    {
        "id": "e2022f3797213292",
        "type": "tab",
        "label": "Fireplace Automation",
        "disabled": false,
        "info": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "18112a371a5730af",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Start or Reset Timers",
        "func": "if (msg.payload === 'on') {\n    // Fireplace turned on\n    return [msg, null]; // Start timers\n} else {\n    // Fireplace turned off\n    return [null, msg]; // Reset timers\n}",
        "outputs": 2,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 1140,
        "y": 100,
        "wires": [
            [
                "26de0bc92b3c1fa2"
            ],
            [
                "49c2de739512f63e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "26de0bc92b3c1fa2",
        "type": "link out",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Start Timers",
        "links": [
            "9bb3cef0f93bc9ca",
            "10192ba7e96e6de6"
        ],
        "x": 1305,
        "y": 60,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "49c2de739512f63e",
        "type": "link out",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Reset Timers",
        "links": [
            "96384ada3ddffe94",
            "9f9c274ad7a7daf4"
        ],
        "x": 1305,
        "y": 120,
        "wires": []
    },
    {
        "id": "9bb3cef0f93bc9ca",
        "type": "link in",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Auto-Off Timer In",
        "links": [
            "26de0bc92b3c1fa2",
            "3aaa3b66d3c867c9"
        ],
        "x": 605,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "07dd056055f5c8d0"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "07dd056055f5c8d0",
        "type": "api-current-state",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Is Auto-Off Enabled?",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 3,
        "outputs": 2,
        "halt_if": "on",
        "halt_if_type": "str",
        "halt_if_compare": "is",
        "entity_id": "input_boolean.auto_off_fireplace",
        "state_type": "str",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "auto_off",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            }
        ],
        "for": 0,
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "x": 740,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "d77b4e28dd6bb6b7"
            ],
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "d77b4e28dd6bb6b7",
        "type": "api-current-state",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Get Auto-Off Timing",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 3,
        "outputs": 1,
        "halt_if": "",
        "halt_if_type": "num",
        "halt_if_compare": "is",
        "entity_id": "input_number.auto_off_fireplace_timing",
        "state_type": "num",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "auto_off_timing",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            }
        ],
        "for": 0,
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "x": 960,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "be97b45c9eff76da"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "be97b45c9eff76da",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Set Auto-Off Timer",
        "func": "const timingMinutes = Number(msg.auto_off_timing);\n\nif (isNaN(timingMinutes) || timingMinutes <= 0) {\n    node.error(\"Invalid timing value\", msg);\n    return null;\n}\n\nconst timingMilliseconds = timingMinutes * 60 * 1000;\n\nmsg.delay = timingMilliseconds;\ndelete msg.reset;\nreturn msg;\n",
        "outputs": 1,
        "timeout": "",
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 1170,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "d747581c05875140"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "d747581c05875140",
        "type": "trigger",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Auto-Off Timer",
        "op1": "",
        "op2": "",
        "op1type": "nul",
        "op2type": "pay",
        "duration": "0",
        "extend": false,
        "overrideDelay": false,
        "units": "ms",
        "reset": "stop",
        "bytopic": "all",
        "topic": "delay",
        "outputs": 1,
        "x": 1420,
        "y": 340,
        "wires": [
            [
                "f1a9129f98b8ffe6"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "96384ada3ddffe94",
        "type": "link in",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Auto-Off Timer Reset",
        "links": [
            "49c2de739512f63e"
        ],
        "x": 605,
        "y": 400,
        "wires": [
            [
                "76c598a7f58e7ef2"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "76c598a7f58e7ef2",
        "type": "change",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Reset Auto-Off Timer",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "set",
                "p": "reset",
                "pt": "msg",
                "to": "stop",
                "tot": "str"
            }
        ],
        "action": "",
        "property": "",
        "from": "",
        "to": "",
        "reg": false,
        "x": 1160,
        "y": 400,
        "wires": [
            [
                "d747581c05875140"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "3aaa3b66d3c867c9",
        "type": "server-state-changed",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Auto-Off Timing Changed",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 6,
        "outputs": 1,
        "exposeAsEntityConfig": "",
        "entities": {
            "entity": [
                "input_number.auto_off_fireplace_timing"
            ],
            "substring": [],
            "regex": []
        },
        "outputInitially": false,
        "stateType": "str",
        "ifState": "",
        "ifStateType": "str",
        "ifStateOperator": "is",
        "outputOnlyOnStateChange": true,
        "for": "0",
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "ignorePrevStateNull": false,
        "ignorePrevStateUnknown": false,
        "ignorePrevStateUnavailable": false,
        "ignoreCurrentStateUnknown": false,
        "ignoreCurrentStateUnavailable": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "payload",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            },
            {
                "property": "data",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "eventData"
            },
            {
                "property": "topic",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "triggerId"
            }
        ],
        "x": 150,
        "y": 360,
        "wires": [
            [
                "0598fdc1b02c8e8a"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "6aed46c49381ad76",
        "type": "server-state-changed",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Switch Fireplace Pressed",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 6,
        "outputs": 1,
        "exposeAsEntityConfig": "",
        "entities": {
            "entity": [
                "switch.fireplace"
            ],
            "substring": [],
            "regex": []
        },
        "outputInitially": false,
        "stateType": "str",
        "ifState": "",
        "ifStateType": "str",
        "ifStateOperator": "is",
        "outputOnlyOnStateChange": true,
        "for": "0",
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "ignorePrevStateNull": false,
        "ignorePrevStateUnknown": false,
        "ignorePrevStateUnavailable": false,
        "ignoreCurrentStateUnknown": false,
        "ignoreCurrentStateUnavailable": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "payload",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            },
            {
                "property": "data",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "eventData"
            },
            {
                "property": "topic",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "triggerId"
            }
        ],
        "x": 150,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "a1d29d4c48c3b409"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "bcf26e334a507ef8",
        "type": "switch",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "",
        "property": "payload",
        "propertyType": "msg",
        "rules": [
            {
                "t": "eq",
                "v": "on",
                "vt": "str"
            },
            {
                "t": "eq",
                "v": "off",
                "vt": "str"
            }
        ],
        "checkall": "true",
        "repair": false,
        "outputs": 2,
        "x": 570,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "ae08ca697b2675c4"
            ],
            [
                "e27da748b8161e01"
            ]
        ],
        "outputLabels": [
            "on",
            "off"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a1d29d4c48c3b409",
        "type": "api-current-state",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Check Fireplace State",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 3,
        "outputs": 1,
        "halt_if": "",
        "halt_if_type": "str",
        "halt_if_compare": "is",
        "entity_id": "input_boolean.fireplace_onoff",
        "state_type": "str",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "outputProperties": [
            {
                "property": "fireplaceState",
                "propertyType": "msg",
                "value": "",
                "valueType": "entityState"
            }
        ],
        "for": 0,
        "forType": "num",
        "forUnits": "minutes",
        "x": 400,
        "y": 80,
        "wires": [
            [
                "bcf26e334a507ef8"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "ae08ca697b2675c4",
        "type": "api-call-service",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Set Fireplace On",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 7,
        "debugenabled": false,
        "action": "input_boolean.turn_on",
        "floorId": [],
        "areaId": [],
        "deviceId": [],
        "entityId": [
            "input_boolean.fireplace_onoff"
        ],
        "labelId": [],
        "data": "",
        "dataType": "jsonata",
        "mergeContext": "",
        "mustacheAltTags": false,
        "outputProperties": [],
        "queue": "none",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "domain": "input_boolean",
        "service": "turn_on",
        "output_location": "",
        "output_location_type": "none",
        "x": 830,
        "y": 40,
        "wires": [
            [
                "18112a371a5730af"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "e27da748b8161e01",
        "type": "api-call-service",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Set Fireplace Off",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 7,
        "debugenabled": false,
        "action": "input_boolean.turn_off",
        "floorId": [],
        "areaId": [],
        "deviceId": [],
        "entityId": [
            "input_boolean.fireplace_onoff"
        ],
        "labelId": [],
        "data": "",
        "dataType": "jsonata",
        "mergeContext": "",
        "mustacheAltTags": false,
        "outputProperties": [],
        "queue": "none",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "domain": "input_boolean",
        "service": "turn_off",
        "output_location": "",
        "output_location_type": "none",
        "x": 830,
        "y": 120,
        "wires": [
            [
                "18112a371a5730af"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "f1a9129f98b8ffe6",
        "type": "api-call-service",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Turn off Fireplace",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 7,
        "debugenabled": false,
        "action": "switch.turn_off",
        "floorId": [],
        "areaId": [],
        "deviceId": [],
        "entityId": [
            "switch.fireplace"
        ],
        "labelId": [],
        "data": "",
        "dataType": "jsonata",
        "mergeContext": "",
        "mustacheAltTags": false,
        "outputProperties": [],
        "queue": "none",
        "blockInputOverrides": true,
        "domain": "switch",
        "service": "turn_off",
        "x": 1670,
        "y": 460,
        "wires": [
            [
                "0bc53e3b2e62d06e"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0598fdc1b02c8e8a",
        "type": "subflow:109ae81398e4db33",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Automation Gate",
        "x": 370,
        "y": 360,
        "wires": [
            [
                "96384ada3ddffe94",
                "9bb3cef0f93bc9ca"
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0bc53e3b2e62d06e",
        "type": "api-call-service",
        "z": "e2022f3797213292",
        "name": "Set Fireplace Off",
        "server": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "version": 7,
        "debugenabled": false,
        "action": "input_boolean.turn_off",
        "floorId": [],
        "areaId": [],
        "deviceId": [],
        "entityId": [
            "input_boolean.fireplace_onoff"
        ],
        "labelId": [],
        "data": "",
        "dataType": "jsonata",
        "mergeContext": "",
        "mustacheAltTags": false,
        "outputProperties": [],
        "queue": "none",
        "blockInputOverrides": false,
        "domain": "input_boolean",
        "service": "turn_off",
        "output_location": "",
        "output_location_type": "none",
        "x": 1870,
        "y": 460,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "d262b87e.b0ac48",
        "type": "server",
        "name": "Home Assistant",
        "version": 5,
        "addon": true,
        "rejectUnauthorizedCerts": true,
        "ha_boolean": "y|yes|true|on|home|open",
        "connectionDelay": true,
        "cacheJson": true,
        "heartbeat": false,
        "heartbeatInterval": "30",
        "areaSelector": "friendlyName",
        "deviceSelector": "friendlyName",
        "entitySelector": "friendlyName",
        "statusSeparator": "at: ",
        "statusYear": "hidden",
        "statusMonth": "short",
        "statusDay": "numeric",
        "statusHourCycle": "h23",
        "statusTimeFormat": "h:m",
        "enableGlobalContextStore": true
    }
]


I would suggest striping all the Home Assistant nodes out of your example (an inject node, function node, trigger node and some debug nodes should be enough)

Also double check your trigger node, it has "overrideDelay": false, set which would imply that it's not using the msg.delay (you need to set this before changing the "wait" choice)

Thanks for this... I will give both of these a whirl today. Appreciate the quick reply!

Thanks @hardillb, I was able to get it working on a test flow.  I did need to set overrideDelay to true, units to ms, and reset message to stop.  TBH, I believe that's how I had it set prior in the larger flow.  I am going to look deeper and add these nodes in 1 by 1.  If it is still failing then I assume there is an issue with interfering payloads.

Using the debugging technique suggested by @hardillb I was able to get this working.
